# NPM HeaderParser

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, nestjs, backend

Hello i have problems when i try to install npm in backend, i don't know why this error is happend, if someone can help me it will be great.

```
 npm audit report
```

dicer  *
Severity: high
Crash in HeaderParser in dicer - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wm7h-9275-46v2
No fix available
node_modules/dicer
busboy  <=0.3.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of dicer
node_modules/busboy
multer  <=2.0.0-rc.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of busboy
node_modules/multer
@nestjs/platform-express  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of multer
node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express

4 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Comment: Seems like some good information in this link https://github.com/expressjs/multer/pull/1097